# java SE 2d game which classes to use for best performance

Tags: java, 2d

i'm porting my J2ME 2D game engine to J2SE and i was wondering which classes should i use to archive the best performance. I'm currently using SingleFameApplication for creating a window, a FrameView for the main game loop and a JPanel for a surface to render on. But this probably wont do..

The problem is when i start the engine in opens a window but when i start executing (rendering + physics + collision detection) it hangs. Can someone explain which classes to use? Should i put the game loop in a new thread (or does frameview have its own thread)? Should i use JFrame instead of SingleFrameApplication?

Comment: Do you have the game loop in the paint() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think choosing the right Frame has much to do with this.

Could you provide more info of the crash / hang? Until then I guess we would be shooting in the dark.

Yes, always a good idea to have the loop in a Thread (with all the critical processing) and only paint when needed. (much like the progress bar analogy)

regards

Comment: It isn't a crash caused by a exception or something else but the window becomes unresponsive (nor close/minimize/maximize work). It looks like the main ui thread is getting blocked. Going to try putting it in a thread and post back.

Comment: i was right, frameview isn't in a thread so it blocked the whole UI thread. Adding a new thread fixed the problem :)